# Handle result from share application

Tags: android, share

I am writing an application to share some data with sharing applications such as facebook, twitter, google+, whatsapp. I am launching a chooser dialog using ACTION_SEND intent in android to list all the share applications and allow to choose whichever application with which user want to share. But I am always getting 0 result in onActivityResult() callback. I would like to know whether my data shared or not and need to keep track of total share count. I googled a lot and everywhere it is mentioned that there is no way to handle result from ACTION_SEND intent. Could you please help me how can I achieve this?. At least I need to know whether my share is successful or not?.